# Is d3.json() function can get json object?

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am new to JQuery / d3js world.

I would like to draw a chart from data in json format.
I saw i some samples that `d3.json(json,f)` function can get only file with data in json format.
My question: is it possible to call it with json like object or string in json format,for example:

```
val jsonStr = { "foo" : "bar"}
d3.json(jsonStr ,f)
```

If not how can I draw a chart with dynamic data (in json format)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have the data as a Javascript variable, you don't need the `d3.json` function. Simply use the name of the variable where ever you would use the argument to the second parameter (the callback function) to `d3.json`.

```
var data = [1,2,3];   
svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.‌​attr("cx", function(d) { return d; })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return d; })
```

Comment: Could you please write a simple example of how it could look?

Comment: `var data = [...]; svg.selectAll("foo").data(data)...`

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: `var data = [1,2,3]; svg.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter().append("circle").attr("cx", function(d) { return d; }).attr("cy", function(d) { return d; })`