# How can I put a json object into a test file ("file.json") and then read that file in a d3.json("file.json", function(error, root))?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg

I am working on a JavaScript project involving the D3 library and trying to make a bubble chart using this code https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4063269 . In my file, I have made a JSON object that is the JSON object I want to put in to the function

```
d3.json("testfin.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
      .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".3em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
});
```

I want to somehow put my JSON object where "testfin.json" goes to make the bubble chart. How can I do this in JavaScript?

The JSON object already has the correct formatting for the function.

Can you help me to either create a file with my JSON object and then read from the file or bypass the testfin.json and just make the function take in the JSON object?

Comment: These two links answer my question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934853/d3-js-loading-json-without-a-http-get

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799571/is-d3-json-function-can-get-json-object

Comment: No offence, but it took you 10 minutes to find several questions that answer your question -- could you please in the future have a closer look before you post the question?

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I should've searched harder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the JSON file reachable on your host.  If it is at the root of the host then `d3.json("testfin.json")` should work, alternatively correct path will depend on your folder structure. I suggest you download the gist https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4063269/download and have a look how it works in the example you refer to.